# Error: Cannot convert value of type 'UInt64' to expected argument type 'DispatchTime'

Tags: swift, swift4

Im trying to create a timer in Swift4 that is controlled by a variable, the only issue is that I get a error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'UInt64' to expected argument type 'DispatchTime'

Here is the code:

```
let maxNumber = maxNumberField.intValue
let amountOfNumbers = amountOfNumbersField.intValue
var delay = 5
var x: Int32 = amountOfNumbers

while(x > 0){

    let when = (DispatchTime.now().uptimeNanoseconds + (5 * UInt64(x)))
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) { // error

        let number = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(maxNumber + 1))
        let synth = NSSpeechSynthesizer()
        synth.startSpeaking(String(number))
    }
    x = (x - 1)
}
```

From my understanding I need to convert the `when` variable which is an `UInt64` to an `DispatchTime`.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either:

- Use [DispatchTime.init(uptimeNanoseconds:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchtime/2300057-init) with your `when` variable.
- Use this: `let when = (DispatchTime.now() + (5 * Double(x)))`, for there is `+` overload for `(DispatchTime, Double)`.